How to run pyrogram with asyncio.gather
from pyrogram import Client, filters
import asyncio

app = Client("Myapi")

async def heart_beat():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(30)
        await beat_function()

async def beat_function():
    await app.send_message("@my_bot_test_grou_p", "I am Alive..!")
    
@app.on_message(filters.chat(-1001798384649))
async def joining(client, message):
    print("triggering")
    if message.entities:
        for entity in message.entities:
            if entity.type.URL:
                if entity.url:
                    try:
                        await app.join_chat(entity.url)
                    except:
                        pass
                if not entity.url:
                    try:
                        await app.join_chat(message.text[entity.offset : entity.offset + entity.length])
                    except:
                        pass

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(heart_beat(), app.start())

asyncio.run(main())

I tried to run the heart_beat() and the joining() function with the asyncio.gather() function. Where the joining() should be running through the pyrogram.app.run() but can't run inside the asyncio
The problem is here the heart_beat() function working and the joining() function not working at all. Please help if anyone know

Have you tried re-writing your main function into two lines: 1. asyncio.create_task(heart_beat()) and 2. await app.run().  In other words, create the Task first, before starting the pyrogram loop.

from pyrogram import Client, filters
import asyncio

app = Client("Myapi")

async def heart_beat():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(30)
        await beat_function()

async def beat_function():
    await app.send_message("@my_bot_test_grou_p", "I am Alive..!")

@app.on_message(filters.chat(-1001798384649))
async def joining(client, message):
    print("triggering")
    if message.entities:
        for entity in message.entities:
            if entity.type == "url":
                url = entity.url or message.text[entity.offset : entity.offset + entity.length]
                try:
                    await app.join_chat(url)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Failed to join chat: {e}")

async def main():
    # Start the Pyrogram client without blocking
    await app.start()
    # Run the heart_beat function and keep the app active with app.idle()
    await asyncio.gather(heart_beat(), app.idle())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

If you're trying to run Pyrogram with asyncio.gather() so that both your heart_beat() function and the joining() handler work properly, the main issue is that app.run() is a blocking call and doesn't integrate well with asyncio.gather().
Solution:
Use app.start() instead of app.run() to start the client without blocking.
Use app.idle() to keep the bot running and listening for incoming messages.
Explanation:
app.start() starts the Pyrogram client without blocking, allowing other asyncio tasks to run. app.idle() keeps the app running and processing events, integrating well with asyncio.gather() to ensure heart_beat() runs in parallel.
This way, both your heart_beat() function and event handling in Pyrogram will run concurrently.

Hello, thank you for responce but it gave me an error : Client object has no attribute idle()

If app.idle() isn’t available, use await asyncio.Event().wait() to keep your program running. Replace app.idle() with await asyncio.Event().wait().
